# My dialog box produces an error when clicked

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to open a dialog when user clicks on the mail icon. However, everything seems to work but I get an error on console included below:

```
    index.js:1 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://fb.me
    in div (created by Transition)
    in Transition (created by ForwardRef(Fade))
    in ForwardRef(Fade) (created by ForwardRef(Backdrop))
    in ForwardRef(Backdrop) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Backdrop)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Backdrop)) (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in ForwardRef(Portal) (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in ForwardRef(Modal) (created by ForwardRef(Dialog))
    in ForwardRef(Dialog) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Dialog)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Dialog)) (at emailPopUp.js:40)
    in emailPopUp (at NavigationBar.js:52)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at NavigationBar.js:51)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at NavigationBar.js:50)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Toolbar))
    in ForwardRef(Toolbar) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Toolbar)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Toolbar)) (at NavigationBar.js:49)
    in header (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by ForwardRef(AppBar))
    in ForwardRef(AppBar) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(AppBar)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(AppBar)) (at NavigationBar.js:48)
    in NavigationBar (at App.js:9)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
```

I am learning react.js and have no clue what is happening. Can you help me with what the error means and how I can fix the problem?

My source code is included below:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent'
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText'
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle'
import { Grid, TextField } from '@material-ui/core'
import EmailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Email'
import { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class emailPopUp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             open : false,
        }
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this)
        this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this)
    }
    
    handleClose(){
        this.setState({
            open : false
        }
        )
    }
    handleOpen(){
        this.setState({
            open : true
        }
        )
    }

    render() {
        return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <EmailIcon onClick={this.handleOpen}/>
            <Dialog open={this.state.open} >
                <DialogTitle>
                    Thank you.
                </DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText>
                        Thank you for showing interest in me. Please compose a message for me.
                    </DialogContentText>
                    <br/>
                    <TextField autoFocus margin='dense' label="Your Body mess" defaultValue="Random Text." type="text"/>
                    <Button onClick={()=>{
                        window.open('mailto:'+"random@gmail.com"+'?cc='+"Ola"+'&subject='+"Hey"+'&body='+"emailBody", '_self');
                        // this.handleClose()
                    }}>Send</Button>
                </DialogContent>
            </Dialog>
        </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default emailPopUp
```

Comment: These type of errors aren't common and hard to debug without seeing whole project. Could you provide GitHub repository?

Answer (score 1):

It's a warning, not an error. You can in 99% of cases ignore these kinds of warnings. You seem to be using material-UI library, which may be using some deprecated functions. Deprecated functions and methods are old functions and methods that will get removed in later versions of a software (in this case react). So probably you may need to update material-UI library, or if it is already newest version, you can ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try that ?

```
<Dialog open={this.state.open}>
  <DialogTitle>Thank you.</DialogTitle>
  <DialogContent>
    <DialogContentText>
      Thank you for showing interest in me. Please compose a message for me.
      <br />
      <TextField
        autoFocus
        margin='dense'
        label='Your Body mess'
        defaultValue='Random Text.'
        type='text'
      />
    </DialogContentText>
    <DialogActions>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          window.open(
            'mailto:' +
              'random@gmail.com' +
              '?cc=' +
              'Ola' +
              '&subject=' +
              'Hey' +
              '&body=' +
              'emailBody',
            '_self'
          );
          // this.handleClose()
        }}
      >
        Send
      </Button>
    </DialogActions>
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>;
```

I assumed you are using Material-ui.

Based on the documentation, I added `DialogActions` for your button, and I placed the `TextField` inside the `DialogContentText`.

Also, are you using Transition ? Your code does not show any use of it (If your code is based on Material-ui) but the error seems related to this feature.

Comment: I am not using a transition. The suggested solution still produces an error.